# gnome shell system monitor applet not work in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, system-monitor, 19.04

I think system monitor applet not compatible with Gnome 3.32, so not work in 19.04

Answer (score 3):

Your options:

1. Either wait for a new release of the applet, current version ain't compatible with Ubuntu 19.04
2. If you know your way around terminals and git, just clone the applet git repository somewhere and `make install` it, the master branch works.

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet.git
   make install
   ```

   Then just log out and back in your sessions to restart gnome-shell, I got the following result:

[image]

Quite happy to have my dashboard back ;)

Would you drive a car without one ?

---

Initial answer  below:

There's currently an open issue there:

https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet/issues/511

> Does work on Ubuntu 19.04 with Wayland. X11 suffers from "LOOOOOOONNNNG login times with system-monitor enabled" as described in [#515](https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet/issues/515) (login not possible at all)

Ubuntu 19.04 is still a little fresh and rough around the corner, either try to DIY or simply wait for the next stable release on https://snapcraft.io/gnome-system-monitor

Edit: check the [applet README](https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet#manual-installation) if you reaaally wanna test (and improve ? ;) ) the master branch of the git repository.